# MDX equivalent to LIKE

Tags: ssas, mdx

In `SQL` I like to search a column for matches of a particular string using something like this:

```
SELECT t.attributeNAME
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.attributeNAME LIKE '%searchString%'
```

I might like to use that in a temp table and then use the result in subsequent sections of a longer script like so:

```
--find the keys
SELECT t.attributeKEY
INTO #Temp
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.attributeNAMELIKE '%searchString%'

--use the keys
SELECT SUM(f.measure)
FROM myFacts f
   INNER JOIN #Temp t ON
    f.attributeKEY = t.attributeKEY

--use the keys again
SELECT SUM(F.measure)
FROM myOtherFacts F
   INNER JOIN #Temp t ON
    F.attributeKEY = t.attributeKEY
```

Is there an equivalent to this in `MDX`? If I have an idea what items from a hierarchy that I'm after can I somehow use a searchString to filter to a specific set of items?

---

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Marc Polizzi answer it seems like `instr` is very useful in this situation and I can do the following:

```
CREATE SET [xCube].[Set_Names] AS
    {FILTER(
    [xDimension].[xHierarchy].[xLevel].Members,
    (InStr(1, [xDimension].[xHierarchy].CurrentMember.NAME, "WIL") <> 0) 
        )
        }

GO

SELECT  
    NON EMPTY 
           [Set_Names]
    ON ROWS,
    NON EMPTY
           [Measures].[x] 
    ON COLUMNS
FROM [xCube]  

GO

SELECT  
    NON EMPTY 
           [Set_Names]
    ON ROWS,
    NON EMPTY
           [Measures].[y] 
    ON COLUMNS
FROM [xCube]  

GO

SELECT  
     NON EMPTY 
           [Set_Names]
     ON ROWS,
     NON EMPTY
           [Measures].[z] 
     ON COLUMNS
FROM [xCube]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to use the [Instr](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh758424.aspx) function even if it does not support wildcard.

Comment: +1 ok - let me play around and add an attempt to the OP Marc.

Comment: - recently added this other MDX question Marc: [SO QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375416/test-if-a-set-exists-before-trying-to-drop-it?noredirect=1#comment27019375_18375416)

Comment: @whytheq : checked the question - no idea if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing like `like` in plain MDX, but there is an implementation in the ASSP project: http://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StringFilters&referringTitle=Home

Comment: i suspect our administrators will not want this code installed - but thanks (+1) anyway it looks like a possible future reference