# Test if a set exists before trying to drop it

Tags: ssas, mdx

In `SQL` before dropping a table I will check if it exists first so as not to cause an error, like so:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#table') IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN 
      DROP TABLE #table 
  END
```

In `MDX` I could do with a way of checking if a `set` or `member` already exists before trying to drop it.

Currently I have the following stucture within some of my `.mdx` files. I add a custom set to the cube and then use that set in several scripts that follow i.e. they are mult-batch scripts.

```
/*
//I run the following manually...
DROP SET [XCube].[xSet]
*/

CREATE 
    SET [XCube].[xSet] AS
        blah blah

1.
SELECT x FROM XCube USING variousconditions AND xSet
GO

2.
SELECT y FROM XCube USING variousconditions AND ySet
GO

3.
SELECT y FROM XCube USING variousconditions AND ySet
GO
```

Putting the above context to one side my question is quite simple:

How do I test if `xSet` exists so that I can execute `DROP SET [XCube].[xSet]` only if required?

Comment: What is the context in which you want to do this? Lengthy batch scripts are not very common for SSAS. Sets can be created 1) in the calculation script, 2) in a user session 3) in the `WITH` clause of a query. An at least for 1 and 3 you know the complete environment, and for 2 you are also controlling what you do. The only reason I see would be to avoid name clashes for 2 and 3 with sets already existing from 1 and 2. But choosing reasonable names should avoid this in most cases, especially as in practice, you have just a handful of sets per cube.

Comment: @FrankPl OK - let me edit the OP to give you an idea of the context although really my question is quite simple - "How do I test for the existence of a custom set without throwing an error?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a partial answer: You can find information about the objects of your cubes in [schema rowsets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms126233.aspx), which are similar to the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views in relational databases. From SQL Server 2008 onwards, you can access these with a limited subset of SQL (no joins, just simple `column_name = 'value'` conditions in the where clause, ...) like this:

```
select * 
  from $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_SETS
 where SET_NAME = 'xSet'
   and CUBE_NAME = 'XCube'
```

Analysis Services automatically detects if the query is SQL or MDX (or, from SQL2012, DAX).

This would give you one record back if the set exists, and none if it does not exist. But I am not aware of a mechanism within MDX to execute code conditionally based on the result.

Comment: that is interesting and the lack of conditional possibilities is surprising and warrants a new question